# Creating sql database in practice - what does the ":str" means that is included in self class

Tags: python, sql

[source:https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-sql-practice-database-with-python-d320908e1faf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbPMR.png)

Is there someone that understands what is happening here? I mainly don't understand what does the ":str" means that is included in self class.

If it is too basic for stackoverflow, please let me know what documentation should I read or what resources to use, thank you.

Comment: A question here is supposed to be self-contained. I.e. copy-and-paste the part(s) you don't understand.

Comment: server:str, db:str and so on

Comment: Too little, we need the context.

Comment: context is in the link from medium that you can copy

Answer (score 0):

In this circumstance, the :str means the type of data that will be used for the connection
So the server, db, uid, and pwd, are all string values.
Strings contain letters or numbers, or both at the same time.

In the top of the code, it has a few more types of data, like the Integer which is all whole numbers only, and date, etc.

Comment: Do note that in Python they are just annotations, and absolutely nothing is checking them at runtime. These annotations are also completely unrelated to `Integer` and all of those other _SQLAlchemy_ types.